# What is the scale ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, foundations, ratio

A draftsperson wishes to produce a scale drawing of a house's floor plan. The actual dimensions of the house are to be 60 ft by 32 ft. The scale rate for the drawing is 1 in. represents 1.25 ft.

Firstly, what's the difference between a scale rate and a scale ratio? How can I find the scale ratio given the scale rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glance at [scale rate](https://www.gov.uk/expenses-and-benefits-cash-sum-payments/scale-rate-payments) and similar pages shows that *scale rate* is not what you are talking about.  [Scale ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(ratio)) is.  In your example, 1 inch = 1.25 feet, so the ratio is 1:15, or 1/15 (because there are 15 inches in 1.25 feet).

Added 10 hours later: One can also say just plain *scale*.  "The scale is 1:15" is probably more common than "the scale ratio is 1:15", and equally correct.